# How to save Pandas DataFrame into S3

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I worked in PySpark using Pandas module and got Pandas DataFrame. I would like to save this as csv in specific bucket in s3.

I tried this, but it gives me an IOerror

```
result_df.to_csv("s3n://id:pw@bucket_name/")
```

How can I do this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Pandas DataFrames cannot be saved directly to S3. Just use Spark DataFrame and method described by Joe Widen.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Spark are you using?

If you're using 1.4 or later, use the Dataframe writer and Databricks csv write format:

```
(result_df.write
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("s3n://id:pw@bucket_name/"))
```